# Slow navigation when inheriting from a base form

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation

I am using a base form that has a menu on it so that I don't have to re-do the code for the whole application.

Essentially this form is called StudentBase.cs

Then I have another form called StudentProfile that inherits from StudentBase

```
    public partial class StudentProfile : StudentBase
    {
       public string selectedPage;
    }
```

This then inherits the menu that is in StudentBase and I don't have to re-do the menu.

On the menu, there are buttons for the individual forms.

So let's say I press on Student Profile I use this to navigate:

```
    private void btnProfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //I don't want the page to reload if it is the current page
          if (selectedPage != "Profile") 
          {
             StudentProfile profile = new StudentProfile();
             profile.Show();
             this.Hide();
          }      
    }
```

Doing this produces a very laggy result, as well as it looks very glitchy

I override selectedPage in the child forms so in the case of StudentProfile I use:

```
   private void StudentProfile_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedPage = "Profile";
    }
```

I have tested this on my friend's code and his navigation works without lag or glitch. He didn't do the inheritance on the form

Comment: Incomplete. Where does selectedPage come from ?  But inheriting a menu runs the risk of having multiple copies active. When you click someother menu item, how many times doe sit fire?

Comment: I added the selected page now. How can I check the number of times that it fires? I can tell you that the moment I click the menu item there is a massive jump in memory

Comment: The proper way is to use UserControls and load them into your MainForm.

Comment: I did some research on the UserControls is there any specific video/page which explains how to do it. I tried to do it with a video I watched and a few pages, I assume you use a class to actually be able to add the menu to your toolbox. I can't seem to get that right.

Comment: There is a feature called Menu merging. A ToolStrip could be part of the UserControl (aks Page). Note that you are reinventing MDI here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I couldn't properly figure out how to use the UserControls. I put it on my to-do list so I can try that at the end of the project if I still have time left.

But, I figured out why it was taking so long to move from one navigation to the other.

I was selecting the student details in the base form using

```
Student student = new Student();
Student studentDetailsFound = student.GetStudent(2);
```

I never stopped it from selecting from the database every time it navigates to a new form, thus, the two-second delay every time. 
So there were two options to fix this: **Static variables or caching**.

I used the latter and now it switches to the pages rather fast.

By adding a **transition** on the form, it made it a lot smoother on the eyes.

*Also note*: if you are getting the data like I am you should first wait for the designing of the form to finish. So put the GetStudent part into this if:

```
if (this.Site == null || !this.Site.DesignMode)
{
    studentDetailsFound = GetStudent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your inheritance solution is that when you create an instance of `StudentProfile` you also create an instance of the `StudentBase` form. You show this new instance and hide the old one. You now have two instances of `StudentBase` (one visible and one hidden). As you open more forms from your menu, you get more instances of `StudentBase` in memory. Even though they are hidden they still consume resource. This would explain the result you see.

I suggest you do as your friend, which is by the way the typical way child forms are handled from a main menu.

Comment: Not just resources. They all subscribe to the same events too.